# Schema level deadlock on SQL Server between SELECTS (or other queries) and ALTER ROLE ... ADD MEMBER when creating credentials

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, hashicorp

**Context**

We have a few apps reading and writing to SQL Server. These apps get their credentials at startup from a central Hashicorp vault which creates the credentials at app startup time.

**Problem**

Often (3-5 times a week) we get deadlocks and always the culprit is the same - some innocuous app is running a query (even a simple, single table select statement) and the ALTER ROLE statement is being ran by Hashicorp to add some new credentials for another app to the dbwriter/reader roles.

The role creation SQL looks like this:

```
USE MASTER;

CREATE LOGIN [{{name}}] WITH PASSWORD = N'{{password}}';

USE SomeDb;

CREATE USER [{{name}}] FOR LOGIN [{{name}}];

EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [{{name}}];
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, [{{name}}];
```

The problem appears to occur in the `ALTER ROLE` call made by `sp_addrolemember`.

It appears the `ALTER ROLE` statement acquires a `Sch-m` (Schema Modification) lock on `PERMISSIONS` and then `DATABASE_PRINCIPAL`. Any query (e.g. a `SELECT`) needs to acquire Schema Stability (`Sch-S`) lock on these, which can cause a deadlock (e.g. query locks `DATABASE_PRINCIPAL` first, `ALTER` locks `PERMISSIONS` first).

What I've investigated:

- I very frustratingly cannot recreate this against a dev DBMS - I have tried running a python script to create credentials constantly while querying for data.
- I couldn't find any documentation on how to acquire these locks upfront (e.g. if the user creation code acquired both locks together/waited for them both to be free)

So I would love any ideas about this (or why it may not be recreatable!).

One solution that has been raised is switching to GRANT instead of using roles, apparently this may not take schema modification locks. However, I am unsure if this is truly the case and I don't want to put these changes into production without some assurance that they will improve the situation.

Here's the data from ignite viewer:

The survivor query:

```
/* InputBuf */
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [v-rcon_approle-svc_****_rw-WOqDPce4L742J1mpoMfM-1639090813]

/* Frame 1  procname=adhoc, line=1 */
alter role [db_datareader] add member [v-rcon_approle-svc_****_rw-WOqDPce4L742J1mpoMfM-1639090813]

/* Frame 2  procname=mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_addrolemember, line=47 */
exec (@stmtR

/* Frame 3  procname=adhoc, line=1 */
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [v-rcon_approle-svc_****_rw-WOqDPce4L742J1mpoMfM-1639090813
```

The victim query

```
/* Frame 1  procname=adhoc, line=1 */
SELECT **** ...`
```

Here's the xdl file:

```
<deadlock><victim-list><victimProcess id="process16929ec3088"/></victim-list><process-list><process id="process16929ec3088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 1 PERMISSIONS(class = 100, major_id = 0), lockPartitionId = 11" waittime="2640" ownerId="5731154681" transactionname="Load Permission Object Cache" lasttranstarted="2021-12-10T10:00:13.853" XDES="0x1748f223be8" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="12" kpid="9904" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-10T10:00:13.853" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-10T09:51:34.830" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.830" hostname="***" hostpid="15179" loginname="v-rcon_approle-svc_mars_rts_ro-72LuqPkS958rLBVFBUM8-1639083781" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5731154673" currentdb="31" currentdbname="*****" lockTimeout="4294967295"><executionStack><frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x01001f00804d1e15607b4e1e7f01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT ***  </frame></executionStack><inputbuf>
SELECT ***   </inputbuf></process><process id="process196eff9f468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 1 PERMISSIONS(class = 100, major_id = 0), lockPartitionId = 11" waittime="3047" ownerId="5731154594" transactionname="Load Permission Object Cache" lasttranstarted="2021-12-10T10:00:13.450" XDES="0x174e1e9fbe8" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="12" kpid="14048" status="suspended" spid="118" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-10T09:55:58.547" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-10T09:55:58.547" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.547" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="***" hostpid="4904" loginname="****\****" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="0" currentdb="1" currentdbname="master" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056"><executionStack/><inputbuf>
****   </inputbuf></process><process id="process18934ab7848" taskpriority="0" logused="1392" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 31 DATABASE_PRINCIPAL(principal_id = 16390), lockPartitionId = 11" waittime="404" ownerId="5731153668" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-12-10T10:00:13.310" XDES="0x181e7460040" lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="5" kpid="17184" status="suspended" spid="135" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-10T10:00:14.053" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-10T10:00:14.053" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.053" clientapp="vault" hostname="****" hostpid="0" loginname="****\_HCVault_SQL_****" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5731153668" currentdb="31" currentdbname="*****" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056"><executionStack><frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x01001f004dd61113a069b4a77501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
alter role [db_datareader] add member [*****]    </frame><frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_addrolemember" line="47" stmtstart="2544" stmtend="2568" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f9a42b4dd67361d01acad000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec (@stmtR    </frame><frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="200" sqlhandle="0x01001f006d2168174069b4a77501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [****    </frame></executionStack><inputbuf>
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [****]   </inputbuf></process></process-list><resource-list><metadatalock subresource="PERMISSIONS" classid="class = 100, major_id = 0" dbid="1" lockPartition="11" id="lock184944dc100" mode="Sch-M"><owner-list><owner id="process196eff9f468" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait"/></owner-list><waiter-list><waiter id="process16929ec3088" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait"/></waiter-list></metadatalock><metadatalock subresource="PERMISSIONS" classid="class = 100, major_id = 0" dbid="1" lockPartition="11" id="lock184944dc100" mode="Sch-M"><owner-list><owner id="process18934ab7848" mode="Sch-M"/></owner-list><waiter-list><waiter id="process196eff9f468" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait"/></waiter-list></metadatalock><metadatalock subresource="DATABASE_PRINCIPAL" classid="principal_id = 16390" dbid="31" lockPartition="11" id="lock1760380e580" mode="Sch-S"><owner-list><owner id="process16929ec3088" mode="Sch-S"/></owner-list><waiter-list><waiter id="process18934ab7848" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait"/></waiter-list></metadatalock></resource-list></deadlock>
```

Comment: You should be able to add traces to capture deadlock events and details. If you already have deadlock details, please add them to you question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand any query requires a Schema Stability lock so it can read data - this is unavoidable and done by MSSQL in the backend as far as I understand. Normally these locks have no effect, unless you are doing DDL stuff which creates schema modification locks.

Let me try and pull this file .

Comment: So the problem is the schema stability locks it creates. That's normal and unavoidable: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207433/how-to-avoid-a-select-query-for-holding-a-sch-s-lock

I think the weird bit is the alter role membership causing a schema modification lock... Or it leas tif there was a way to acquire the liocks it needs in one go to avoid deadlock

Comment: Yep - my apologies but I can't share too many internal details without a whole mess of questions:

the query is a SELECT DISTINCT (some columns) FROM (table) INNER JOIN (table2) ON (a few join conditions, table1.x = table2.x) WHERE (a few where column = constant conditions).

I can also see a few queries writing to the database with inserts, etc that got deadlocked in a similar way in other incidents.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat unsatisfactory resolution: We switched the most frequently used query from ALTER ROLE... to GRANT and the deadlocks stopped happening (we were seeing 20-30 every day so it's pretty easy to see they've stopped).

Clearly there's some behaviour in ALTER ROLE that creates a much higher level of locking than with simple grants.

Comment: do you move tables between schemas?